# Implementation code of Braintree to the django project

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, braintree

I want to implement a subscription code from Braintree payment gateway to my Django project. Example I find here: https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/python/guide/recurring_billing 
I have the below code which is responsible for creating subscriptions - it works in a single file (not in my django application).

When I moved to the method code in django, I get code 405.

**My code:**

```
def subscriptions():
    try:
        customer_id = client.customer.id
        customer = braintree.Customer.find(customer_id)
        payment_method_token = client.customer.credit_cards[0].token
        result = braintree.Subscription.create({
            "payment_method_token": payment_method_token,
            "plan_id": "myPlanId"
        })
        print result
        if result.is_success:
            print "Subscription success!"
    except braintree.exceptions.NotFoundError:
        print "No customer found."
```

**My url**

```
url(r'^subscription/$', subscriptions, name='subscription'),
```

Comment: Is the `subscriptions` method you posted your actual view code? Or is it just a helper function you are calling from the view?